# i am trying to write the contents of logfile in shell script in an email rather than go to logfile and open it to see the result

Tags: shell

I am creating a Scala class that compared source count and target count and display the columns that don't match with source.
The output will be logged in shell script log files but I want the contents of the log file to be sent in email. Can you please suggest what method can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a local MTA and got it set up correctly you can just do it like this:

```
mail -s "subject here" email@address.com <<< log.file
```